# Building a customized form in Teams site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, team-sites, powerapps-forms, microsoft-teams

We are using the backend site collection from Teams as our sandbox for Power Apps development. I want to build a customized form from a SharePoint list using Power Apps. I see the option in our regular site collection, but not in the Teams site collection. Is that a limitation of Teams? Is there a setting to allow customized forms?

The final product will be on the client's site collection, but we would prefer to do development in our sandbox. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: When you open site collection in SharePoint and navigate to list, do you see Integrate > Power Apps option? Is this for all lists in the site or specific lists? If specific list, which list template used for creating this list?

Comment: I think you are on to something. Please add this as an answer.

Comment: Added answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following this steps:

1. Go to your list tab inside Microsoft Teams
2. Click on ellipses (**...**) at top and select **Open in SharePoint**:

   [image]
3. When you open list in SharePoint, click on **Integrate** from top command bar and then select **Power Apps** > **Customize forms**:

   [image]

Check this documentation for more information: [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)

---

**Note**: SharePoint lists created using classic list templates might not have the Integrate > Power Apps option as they don't support customizing list forms using Power Apps.

Comment: You were on the right track. Turns out the list I wanted was not a custom list, I assumed it was. Every custom list on my subsite allowed me to see the Integrate tab, the one I wanted to use did NOT. I think it was a Tasks list or something else. So, Teams wasn't the issue, the list template was.

Comment: Yes, lists created using classic list templates might not have the integrate > power apps option.